# Is the plural verb "were" correct considering the supplement?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

That book — and this one — ***were*** particularly intriguing to me, someone who has known the family for years.

Source:- https://www.washingtonpost.com/entertainment/books/donald-antrims-one-friday-in-april-is-a-vital-book-about-mental-illness-and-recovery/2021/10/21/c01f6170-207c-11ec-8200-5e3fd4c49f5e_story.html

Comment: The fact that the second book is mentioned in the supplement does not change the fact that there are two books. Were is the correct form to use.

Comment: It's slightly awkward, but such sentences are quite common to indicate the development of thought processes or changing situations. There's [a similar question with brackets not dashes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/218275/help-needed-is-or-are) and [one with commas](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294952/singular-vs-plural-with-parenthetical-and-clause), and answers differ depending on how relevant/significant/closely-linked the parenthetical (second) part is. Here, I think the plural sounds better, because it applies equally to both books.

Comment: Other similar questions https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/137227/difficulties-with-deciding-whether-it-is-a-plural-or-singular https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/264451/should-i-use-make-or-makes-in-this-sentence https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/285249/the-student-as-well-as-x-does-it-use-a-plural-form

Comment: Yes, the plural verb is correct. The supplement is relevant to determining the the form of the verb.

Comment: I agree with "were" being correct. That said, these constructions can be awkward even for native speakers. When I'm writing, often I rewrite the sentence to avoid them. "These two books were particularly intriguing to me" or "That book--much like this book--was particularly intriguing to me"